# More efficient approach to create a dummy coding

Tags: r

**Question:** *In Python, I would work with dictonaries and use lots of map/apply functions. However, with R I started with this simple approach using lists, and I would like to know whether there is a more efficient/more elegant approach to doing the following.*

In statistics, you use dummy variables to represent levels of a nominal attribute. E.g., A/B/C would become 00, 01, 10. A/B/C/D would become 000, 001, 010, 100. Thus, only one 1 per item is allowed. You therefore need `n-1` numbers to represent `n` variables/letters.

Here I create some data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  "upper" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), # var 1
  "country" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), # var 2
  "price" = c(1,2,3,2,3,1,3,1,2) # var 3
)
```

Create a list with keys (attributes) and values (lists of unique attribute levels):

```
lst <- list()
for (attribute in colnames(data)) {
  lst[[attribute]] = unique(data[[attribute]])
}
```

Create dummy coding, `i` is used to consider only `n-1` items:

```
dummy <- list()
for (attribute in colnames(data)) {
  i <- 1
  for (level in lst[[attribute]]) {
    if (length(lst[[attribute]])!=i) {
      dummy[[paste0(attribute, level)]] <- ifelse(
        data[[attribute]]==level,
        1,
        0
      )
    }
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
```

Results:

```
dummy
$upper1
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

$upper2
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0

$country1
[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0

$country2
[1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0

$price1
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0

$price2
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: In R, you rarely have to do dummy encoding yourself. Most modeling functions do it for you if you pass them a factor variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a design matrix using `model.matrix`, `split` the columns to create a `list` of `list`, finally, concatenate the `list` elements together (`do.call(c,..`).

```
res <- do.call("c",lapply(data, function(x) {
            x1 <- model.matrix(~0+factor(x))
               split(x1, col(x1))}))
```

As we only need the first two levels, we can subset the 'res' using `c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)` which will recycle to the end of the `list`.

```
res[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]
#$upper.1
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

#$upper.2
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0

#$country.1
#[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0

#$country.2
#[1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0

#$price.1
#[1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0

#$price.2
#[1] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Great solution! Could you explain the part inside `model.matrix`?

Comment: @Xiphias We remove the intercept column by using `the formula `9+`